# Is it possible to force NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to pull updates from the cloud?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, cloudkit

**Backstory:** Push notifications are currently buggy for Mac apps made with Catalyst. This means that changes made on other devices will not be received if the sync engine is CloudKit or `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. As a temporary workaround while waiting for the bug fixes around push notifications on Mac Catalyst, our app needs to periodically and/or manually request a refresh of anything that syncs.

**Question:** How can we request a refresh for the default instance of `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`? (Apple's documentation shows nothing here.)

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore/1415989-synchronize) it is not possible to force NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to pull updates from the cloud. You can only let iCloud know that new keys and values are available to be uploaded. using the Instance Method [synchronize()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore/1415989-synchronize)

> The **system controls** when those keys and values are
>   **uploaded**. The frequency of upload requests for key-value storage is
>   limited to several per minute.

The recommended time to call `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.synchronize()` is upon app launch, or upon returning to the foreground.